# Kernel of the non-injective homomorphism $S_3$ to $S^1$ where the kernel is non trivial

Tags: group-theory

Let $S^{1} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \, : \, |z|=1 \}$.
Let $\phi : S_3 \to S^1$ be a non- injective homomorphism whose kernel is nontrivial. What is the order of the kernel of $\phi$?

---

By Lagrange Theorem, the kernel of $\phi$ can be then $2$ or $3$. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is a normal subgroup and the order of the normal subgroup of $S^3$ is $3$.